# Adding tool tip for drop-down elements in JSF

Tags: jsf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >

    <h:body>



        <h1>JSF 2  example</h1>

        <h:form id="form1">

            <h3>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['welcome.jsf']}" />
            </h3>


            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                Language : 
                <h:selectOneMenu id="combo1" value="#{language.localeCode}" onchange="submit()"
                    valueChangeListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}">

                <f:selectItems value="#{language.countriesInMap}" title="#{language.localeCode}" />

                </h:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>


        </h:form>

        <h:form id="form11">

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                Language : 
                <h:selectOneMenu id="combo11" value="#{language.localeCode}" onchange="submit()"
                    valueChangeListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}">

                <f:selectItems value="#{language.countriesInMap}" title="#{language.localeCode}" />

                </h:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>


        </h:form>
        <script>
    window.onload = function(var var1,var var2) {
        var var1="form1";
        var var2="combo1";

         var options = document.getElementById(var1+":"+var2).options;
         for(var i = 0; i &lt; options.length; i++) {
                     options[i].title = "#{msg['welcome.jsf']}";
         }
    }   
    </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I am using the above xhtml code to create two dropdowns .
Using the above JavaScript function, I am able to create tool tips for first drop down elements .
In order to create tool tip for second drop-down elements,I need to call the above JS function by passing the id's of form and selectItems as parameters to the function.
How can I do this?

Comment: Off Topic: `onchange="submit()"` is an uncommon construct in JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above thing can be achieved by modifying the above code by using "title" tag in selectonemenu tag like below:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu *title="#{language.countriesInMap}"* id="combo1" value="#{language.localeCode}" onchange="submit()"
                    valueChangeListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}">

                <f:selectItems value="#{language.countriesInMap}"  />

                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSF 2.2 you can use passthrough, so you don't need javascript at all:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<!-- your other code -->

Language : 
    <h:selectOneMenu id="combo1" value="#{language.localeCode}" onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}">      
           <c:forEach value="#{language.countriesInMap}" var="language"> 
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{language.countriesInMap}" itemValue="#{language.localeCode}" pt:title="#{msg['welcome.jsf']}"/>    
           </c:forEach>
    </h:selectOneMenu>    
</h:panelGrid>

<!--...second menu like the first one -->
```

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0